# How to use RegionPlot3D to show three different plots in the same graph

Tags: plotting

I have written below code to show 3 different 3D graphs. is it possible to combine the graphs and show all of them in one graph? (Maybe by making them transparent so that, they can be shown in one graph.)

I found this example, but I don't know how to apply it to my case:

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 7 Pi/4}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]]
```

Comment: `Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Ignore `Manipulate` in the linked answer, it is not related to the core issue anyway.